# Erro ao exibir relatório criado com Jasper report em VPS com S.O Linux

Tags: java, linux

Estou com dificuldade para exibir o relatório em uma aplicação hopedada em um **VPS**. Adicionei a font na dependência do projeto **Maven**, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto tento gerar o relatório surge erro:

1º erro:

> Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager

2º erro:

> Could not initialize class
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser

3º erro:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102/jre/lib/i386/libfontmanager.so: libgcc_s.so.1:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Executando pesquisa na Internet, para resolução do problema encontrei opções como: `-Djava.awt.headless=true` para adicionar font dejavu-fonts.
Alguém possui alguma sugestão para ajudar?